# Cannot see hero property on responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I cannot see the image properly in my phone, looks fine in laptop but not in phone, actually i cropped manually and used a different one when is less than 700px, and that doesnt work, i did that cause i use cover for the hero and for this section initially, but even if i use a smaller one for phone and using cover again doesnt work. Any suggestion please?

```css
#hero{
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.1) url('../img/wallpapers/wallpaper_hero.jpg') no-repeat fixed center / cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;


  /*background: rgba(0,0,0,.1) url('../img/wallpapers/wallpaper_hero.jpg') no-repeat fixed center top / cover;*/

}


@media screen and (max-width: 771px) {


  #hero {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.1) url('../img/wallpapers/wallpaper_hero.jpg') no-repeat center / cover;


  }

}
```

```html
<header id="hero">

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <h1>Central de ingredientes</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </header>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwlTa.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKEJQ.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please consider to visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to check out how to ask good questions on SO.

Comment: but there is no way i can use the same image for wider screens if my hero width is huge and using cover right? Is gonna be so pixelated, i need to use a new one and even tho is pixelated. When i redimension the screen of laptop is fine, the problem is when put the page on my server and use with the phone, i tried everything...

Comment: can you try http://www.asociacionaepi.es/curso_web/francisco/practica1/

in the phone
thank you =)

Comment: I'm sorry i deleted my comment because it's not an extension issue, actually `background-image: cover` property is acting as it should be and this is the default behavior for it, if you want to make it responsive you could use the same image just make it cover when it is small without making the `background-size: 100% 100%` because this will make the image stretched which is not a good way.

Comment: @franciscodwq Looking at the website you linked your media query actually just redefines the same image rather than a smaller version/ different file. I presume you've uploaded a version where you change the file too?

Comment: hey, is taking the cropped version when you use a phone, and looks like that ,pixelated, 100% 100% is not a way, even use background-size 100% as well is not a way cause i have a 100vh for my hero image, so is gonna fit all but the rest below is gonna be empty. I dont get why you said to use the same image when is smaller and make it cover, if i do that is gona cover the picture width which is like 200px so is gonna be zoomed :S

Comment: another thing, why when i resize the page with the laptop looks fine and when i publish the page and check the phone is not?

Comment: so? You have any idea? still no working =(

Comment: Hey @AaronMcGuire i made it but i dont exactly get why this is the only solution, actually i used the same image but on responsive i wrote that have to be cover again, if i dont do it is gonna zoom in a lot right? cause is gonna be cover from the initial size, but if i say cover in 771 px is gonna be perfect right? Anyway, if i use position fixed(actually is what i want) doesnt work, only like that you know why?

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding still @franciscodwq in my previous comment I mentioned that the link you provided had the same image on multiple breakpoints - what I meant by this is that although you are redefining your breakpoint you have not added a smaller image file and therefore the image will look exactly the same. I think you may be confused as to how the media query works - the media query tells the browser to do something when it hits that specific width. It doesn't affect width or height of elements unless you have specified it to do so - I will add a snippet now try and explain

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your example URL it looks like you may be confusing media-queries here is a basic example of how the query should work:

Basically, when the browser is from `0-770px` it will show the `smaller`  image file and when its `771px+` it will show the `larger` image.

*Expand the snippet and resize your browser to see the image change*

```css
.hero {
  background-image:url(http://via.placeholder.com/1600x600);
  background-position:center center;
  background-size:cover;
  height:100vh;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 770px){

  .hero {
    background-image:url('http://via.placeholder.com/770x400');
  }  
}
```

```html
<section class='hero'>
<section class='hero__content'>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, i get that, but i dont get why i cannot use a background image for a section IN RESPONSIVE but FIXED, works in the original size but not with media queries, this is the only way i can see the image in a phone, without beign fixed and using cover. dont get why?....